# How do I write an 8 bit array to a 16 bit array of 1/2 size

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memcpy

Hey so I'm doing some programming for GBA, and I'm running into a problem.

I have a bitmap FILE that looks something like this:

```
const unsigned char bitheart_Bitmap[9216] = 
{
    0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 
    0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 
    0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 
    0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 
    0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 0x16, 
...}
```

Ofcourse not all the values are 0x16, but you get the point.  What I am trying to do is copy these values into a memory location that holds 16 bit spaces.

How can I write this?

My original code was this:

```
for(ii=0; ii<98; ii++)
{
    memcpy(&vid_mem_front[ii*120], &bitheart_Bitmap[ii*98], 98);
}
```

But again, this only copies 8 bits into a 16 bit space right?

How can I get it to copy two consecutive 8 bit values into a 16 bit space?

Expected output:

```
0x1616, 0x1616, 0x1616, etc.
```

Let me know if this isn't very clear, I'm pretty bad at explaining my problems... Thanks! :)

-punchki

Comment: You should probably just modify the bitmap data  to be {0x1616, 0x1616, ...} which is pretty easy to do with a simple C program for(i=0; i<9216; i+=2) printf("0x%X%X, ",bitheart_Bitmap[i],bitheart_Bitmap[i+1]).

Comment: So sorry guys, I found out the issue I was having!  You are all right, it did write it correctly... The problem I had was I thought sqrt(9216) = 98... when in fact it is 96...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get it to copy two consecutive 8 bit values into a 16 bit space?

Simple example:

```
int8_t a[2];
int16_t b;
memcpy(&b, a, sizeof(a));
```

Now, you can extend that logic to your data.

**Caution**

If you want to treat `b` as a `16` bit integer, you have to account for the endianness of your platform. To make the code endian independent, you can use:

```
b = (a[0] << 8) + a[1];
```

Comment: There could be a problem with endianness, (I don't know if the OP wants to *use* the 16bits values as 16 bit values)

Comment: How come this code: b = (a[0] << 8) + a[1]; is endian independent?

Comment: @Qnoobish, those operations have standards defined behavior, regardless of endianness.

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this.  Given, say,

```
uint8_t bytes[16] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf};
uint16_t shorts[8];
```

A plain memcpy will do the right thing:

```
memcpy(shorts, bytes, sizeof(shorts));
```

Arrays are laid out in memory as contiguous sequences of representations of their element types.